# How can I identify calling view controller in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have 2 View controllers in my storyboard with the same Custom Class.
How can I tell which view controller is being load in viewDidLoad?

Comment: unless you know where you are in your application you can't tell which one is loading...

Comment: You mean 2 VC in SB that are instances of the same class. How are you launching (instantiating) the 2nd VC?

Comment: You should ask yourself why you need to know this. If these view controllers need to behave differently then perhaps they should not be instances of one and the same class.

Comment: the first view controller call the second view controller with segue. I don't know if I'm not supposed to have the same custom class for both, but Chris' answer worked.

Comment: @shinji14 It works, but it's as brittle as identifying views by using tags. What you are doing is unconventional, and you may get better advice by being more specific about why you need to do this, and why you have the same view controller twice in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard, set the restoration identifier (I think it's right under where you set the storyboard ID). Then in `viewDidLoad`, check that identifier:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *restoreID = [self restorationIdentifier];
}
```